# How to use BundleTransformer.Closure for removing unused js & css code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-closure-compiler

There is Google Closure Compiler implementation available for .net BundleTransformer.Closure but no proper documentation, where can one get how to integrate Google Closure Compiler with .Net MVC app?

Answer (score 0):

Closure Compiler will not naturally remove CSS. It works on JavaScript sources, not webpages.